# Why does email attachment fail on rescheduled rule?

Tags: rules, emails

I have an action set component that takes a "date" param and does the following:

1. "Add Variable" saves a path string based on the date.
2. "Execute custom PHP code" saves some data to the path created above.
3. "Send HTML mail to all users of a role" sends an email with the above file attached.
4. "Schedule component evaluation" repeats the component at time +2 minutes and sends date parameter +2 minutes.

If I execute the component, the file is created and the email is sent with the attachment as intended. But when the rescheduled component executes again, the correct file is created on the server and the email is sent, but the attachment is not there.

Comment: as a test, can you include the expected file name in the email - to verify if the attachment code is executing correctly on the reschedule.

Comment: I did exactly that and the filename in the email was correct. Subsequently figured out the problem - see below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to allow the cron user to "Send Arbitrary Files" in the Mime Mail permissions.